# Users and Sessions by Page Path in GA4 aggregated in special way

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, looker

I have the following sample table in Looker using a GA4 data source (page title omitted for privacy):

[image]

The total sessions aggregation shows a number around 0.5 Million. However when exported to excel and summed the actual sum is slightly over 1 Million. Is Google Analytics 4 doing some special calculation to unduplicate page path's where the same session visited them? I would like to use the GA4 api to export sessions by page path however because of this inconsistency when I aggregate in the dashboard using the exported data I'm seeing the incorrect 1 Million value.

Any pointers towards documentation or otherwise would be greatly appreciated. When attempting the same process with a Universal Analytics data source there is no discrepancy. This seems to be a GA4 specific issue and not an issue with any one GA property.

Thank you!

Comment: The 0.5 million is because there might be a session browse multiple page. If there is one session browsing page A and B.
In this report : A , session 1. B , session 1. Total session1
But in excel or other. They will sum the total as 2. Since they don't know they are actually one session. But GA4 does know that

Comment: @darrelltw ya although when I do this with universal it doesn't happen. Also I'm trying to export sessions and users by pagePath to bigquery and I can't do any aggregations because of this issue. Whereas the native connector can. I just want to make sure there's no way around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short summary: the qualification and self-validation of data between GA4 or Looker, and the API are all too different to validate against themselves.

When your data arrives at your GA4 container, it is processed before it is accessible. After it is processed, it can be queried. Looker has it's own processing rules (I believe it *additionally qualifies* the data it gets from GA4). Generally, Looker will display similar numbers to GA.

If you use the GA4 Data Analytics API, you're **not** viewing data under the same processing scrutiny. You may see as much as a 3x increase in sessions when using the API because the API is not going to adhere to any qualifications of how long the sessions were. This applies to other *default* or Google-maintained dimensions and metrics, and they are symptomatically affected in different ways respectively. *The API is great for when you want to make an intricate insight that you know all of the bounds for, and the Looker or GA interface is too cumbersome or uncooperative to get there.*

Comment: can you share where you got this information and how I can learn more about it myself? I'm working on a project to backfill a lot of data from GA4 and would like to have a reference for differences.

Comment: same here, is there any reference where this claim comes from? I didn't find this anywhere on Google's documentation.